# 1980's PC educational game where you build robots

Tags: identify-this-game

I don't remember anything else from this game except it was in the late 1980's in my school and I was playing it on something with a scrollball, and you basically build robots and did science experiments or something. Anyone else remember something like this?

I think it was MS-DOS, or Macintosh. Very hard to say since I didn't know computers at the time. Would've been in grade 2 or 3 around 1986-ish probably.

I think you could customize your robots... It had other games, definitely Number Munchers. Maybe it didn't even have robots... I definitely remember mixing different liquids. I thought I was dumping them on my robots....

Comment: There was a vast amount of educational software written in the 1980's. Where did you go to school?

Comment: I've attempted an answer, but I'm afraid this question is too broad.  Can you narrow down your question by potentially a more specific year or operating system?

Comment: Yes as JAL said, specific years, which country (since your profile doesn't say), school grade etc, what the computer looked like - Did it have an apple on the front? Were the disks 5.25 inch or 3.5 inch? All-in-one keyboard or separate? Etc.

Comment: Here's a [collection of MECC titles](https://archive.org/details/softwarelibrary_apple_mecc) you can search and play online. Only Path Tactics mentions robots, but it doesn't sound like what you're after.

Comment: "grade 2 or 3" implies North America, surely? I think only the US and Canada use that terminology. It's also unlikely that many schools outside of that region would be using MS-DOS or Macintoshes during the 1980s as educational policy is set by government, government seeks to promote local companies, and Microsoft didn't have hegemony yet. (EDIT: plus "customize", with a 'z')

Comment: The expression "I'm in Grade 10" is typically related to a Canadian system. "I'm in 10th Grade" is typically associated with a US system.

Comment: You got it, Canada :)

Comment: So then if you had a scrollball you were likely on a Unisys Icon machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After MUCH searching, I found it. But I can't find ANY details about it.

It's called "Robot R&D" for the Unisys ICON, a computer made for schools in the 80's.

Anyone know where I can find this?!?!

Comment: This enthusiast may have already imaged that floppy: http://www.vcfed.org/forum/showthread.php?58391-Wanted-UNISYS-ICON-floppy-disks-for-imaging

Comment: The [Personal Computer Museum](http://www.pcmuseum.ca/details.asp?id=136) in Brantford, ON has a working ICON system.  You could try contacting them to see if they have it in their archives.

Answer (score 7):

Guessing the most popular Apple II title that fits: [Robot Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Odyssey).

The title page is at Wikipedia, so here is the inside of a robot.

[image]

Comment: This was my first thought. This is really a set of programming challenges disguised as a game for children.

Answer (score 5):

Two games come to mind, both by [The Learning Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Learning_Company):

**Midnight Rescue!** which is a sidescroller with robots released in 1989 for DOS.

[image: Midnight Rescue!]

**Gizmos & Gadgets!** which is an education game with a focus on mechanics, basic electronics, and energy forms.  While it matches your criteria, it was made in 1993 for DOS 3.3.

[image: Gizmos & Gadgets!]

Comment: *Gizmos & Gadgets* was my first thought too, though I don’t recall *building* the robots...

Answer (score 5):

I believe you are referring to **ChipWits**, by Epyx software. It was quite popular at the time.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look familiar... :(

Comment: Hours of fun, with the graphic programming language, and mazes of mixed peril and reward.

Comment: The original programmers tried to launch a modern version a few years ago but never quite finished. http://chipwits.com